# Why is the home directory not created when I create a new user?

Tags: users, useradd

I created a new user (testuser) using the `useradd` command on an Ubuntu server Virtual machine. I would like to create a home directory for the user and also give them root provileges.

However, when I login as the new user, it complains that there is no home directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I answered the main question about creating a home dir. Giving a new user root access is an unrelated issue and should be asked separately. Basically, you just need to add the user to the `sudo` group.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Finally I found how to do this myself:

```
   useradd -m -d /home/testuser/ -s /bin/bash -G sudo testuser
```

`-m` creates the home directory if it does not exist.
`-d` overrides the default home directory location.
`-s` sets the login shell for the user.
`-G` expects a comma-separated list of groups that the user should belong to.

See [`man useradd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/useradd.8.html) for details.

Comment: what is the -d flag doing, or the -G flag doing

Comment: `-m` creates the home directory if it does not exist. `-d` overrides the default home directory location. `-s` sets the login shell for the user. `-G` expects a comma-separated list of groups that the user should belong to.

Comment: One problem I'm having with this method is it doesn't create the default contents in the user dir, like "Downloads" or ".ssh" for example, but there are others.

Answer (score 35):

**Editor's note**: This answer is technically correct to the question as asked, but discussion in the comments clarified that the OP was trying to use `useradd` in a script rather than directly as a shell command, and `adduser` is less suited for that context.

When creating a user interactively, it's generally recommended to use `adduser` rather than `useradd`.

> useradd is a low level utility for adding users. **On Debian,
>
> administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead**.

`adduser` is a friendlier frontend to `useradd` and will do things like create user directories by default. When you run it with only a username as an argument, you will be prompted to provide additional information such as the password:

```
$ sudo adduser testuser
Adding user `testuser' ...
Adding new group `testuser' (1002) ...
Adding new user `testuser' (1002) with group `testuser' ...
Creating home directory `/home/testuser' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for testuser
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n]
```

In general, it's recommended to use use `adduser` instead of `useradd` since this will also set up the required groups automatically. As explained in `man adduser`:

> adduser and addgroup add users and groups to the system according to
> command line options and configuration information in
> /etc/adduser.conf. They are friendlier front ends to the low level
> tools like useradd, groupadd and usermod programs, by default choosing
> Debian policy conformant UID and GID values, creating a home directory
> with skeletal configuration, running a custom script, and other
> features.

Comment: i dont want use adduser command.

Comment: @rajcoumar umm, why? That's the right tool for the job. If you insist on using the wrong tool, you will have to manually create the home directory and the user groups and copy the default files from `/etc/skel` etc., etc. That is why the Official Debian Way® is to use `adduser`.

Comment: #terdon ya correct.. but i am writing a shell script using useradd command only

Comment: @rajcoumar OK,  then you have to either create everything manually,  or just change the script to use adjuster instead.  Just create an /etc/adduser.conf file.

Comment: I tried your approach on CentOS 7, but it does not resolve the problem.  Are you willing to comment?  [here is the link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365263/useradd-cannot-create-directory)

Comment: @CodeMed this is the recommended way for *Debian*-based systems, not CentOS. On CentOS you'll probably need to use `useradd`.

Comment: adduser is an interactive wrapper to useradd - it is not appropriate in scripted solutions, particularly dockerfiles.

Comment: @terdon `useradd` is not deprecated. Like @routhinator has mentioned, `adduser` is a utility that uses `useradd` in conjunction with other utilities to provide a "friendlier frontend". Please remove the "deprecated" statement. [adduser vs useradd](https://askubuntu.com/a/345986/1577007)

Comment: @Brennan on Debian-based systems, it is deprecated in favor of `adduser` as shown in the man page I quoted. It isn't deprecated overall, but this was about Debian where the official advice is to not use `useradd` and use `adduser` instead.

Comment: @terdon : The manpage line you refer to "useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead." - Administrators != scripts. Administrator is a person at an interactive shell. Scripting should use low-level, predictable processes for consistent results in non-interactive conditions.

Comment: @Routhinator the question isn't about scripts, it's about an administrator manually creating a new user. If the question were about scripting, then yes, `useradd` would make more sense since it isn't interactive, but for the purposes of this question, I think that _deprecated_ is right. If you still object, by all means suggest an edit. These are supposed to be collaborative sites, after all :)

Answer (score 5):

```
useradd -m LOGIN
```

creates the user's home directory

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me when I used the command:

```shell
sudo useradd -d /home/ssd2/yuwen yuwen
```

After I typed in that command, there is no such file (I checked by using `cd`&`ls`), and when I use `su yuwen`, it successfully changed into new user, but the home dir was still unchanged (not `ssd2/yuwen` as it supposed to be).

I also use command `cat /etc/passwd` to check if the new user is created. It is created but the home dir is not valid.

The following is the solution if you encounter the same situation like what I described:

1. Login in the linux server using a super user account which could use `sudo`
2. Use `cd` into the dir where you want to put the new user's dir. In my situation, the dir is `/home/ssd2`
3. Use `mkdir` to create the dir for new user, in my case, it is `mkdir yuwen`
4. Use `sudo chown yuwen:yuwen /home/ssd2/yuwen` to let your new user have the ownership.
5. Use `sudo chmod -R yuwen /home/ssd2/yuwen`, authorize it

Then you can use `su yuwen`, after that use `cd ~`, `pwd` to see that you are in the right directory.